# Finding characteres in a game image using Java

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, text-recognition

I'm trying to recognize the characters of a game using Java, so I can process them later.
The images look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQm18.jpg

I want to recognize, specially, the 3w in the left-bottom, the 214 and 0.13 in the center and the 1m in the right-bottom.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any errors? This is too broad. Consider attempting a solution and posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with any errors or issues you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to computer vision and I would suggest using this java OCR library from here:
http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/

This will help you recognize English text present on image. I'm pretty sure that it will give you major texts from image.

PS: For image processing, using matlab or python would be better as they have good computer vision libraries like "Computer vision Toolbox for Matlab" and "OpenCv for python". Here are some examples for you task using matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html